# Como validar datos numericos en IF condicional en Javascript

Tags: javascript, condiciones, validación

Estoy desarrollando un programa de practica en que por medio de prompts se ingresan numeros en un array y se ordenan de menor a mayor, mi problema radica en que no se como hacer para que el numero inicial que pide cuantos numeros quiere ordenar se valide en un IF que no sea con el operador logico !=, existe otra manera de validar un dato numerico? y mi segundo problema radica en que si se ingresa una letra o no se ingresa ningun valor, mi codigo no me muestra los alert, simplemente se cierra. En pocas palabras mi problema esta en el IF, Gracias por la ayuda.

```
let valorInicial = parseInt(prompt(`Con un numero especifica cuantos numeros quieres ordenar`));

if (valorInicial != '') {

   ordernarN()

} else if (valorInicial <= 0 || valorInicial == null) {

   alert('No ingresaste un numero valido')

}

function ordernarN() {

   var array = []

   for (let i = 1; i <= valorInicial; i++) {

      var num = prompt(`ingrese num # ${i}`)

      array.push(num)
   }

   return console.log(array.sort((a, b) => a - b));

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usa `isNan` y `parseInt` de manera que:

- Convertimos strings a números
- Los strings no convertibles devuelven `NaN`

Sabiendo que:

- `NaN` Es considerado como un número

```js
console.log(typeof NaN)
```

Haremos uso de `isNaN` para comprobar que lo que hemos recibido no sea `NaN`

Debido a que `NaN` no se puede identificar sin `isNan`

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```js
let valorInicial = parseInt(prompt("Con un numero especifica cuantos numeros quieres ordenar"));

if (isNaN(valorInicial)) {
  alert('No ingresaste un numero valido');
} else if (valorInicial > 0) {
   ordernarN()
}

function ordernarN() {
   let array = []
   for (let i = 1; i <= valorInicial; i++) {
      var num = prompt(`ingrese num # ${i}`)
      array.push(num)
   }
   console.log(array.sort((a, b) => a - b));
   return;
}
```

Comment: No conocia lo de isNan y Nan y averiguando sobre ello, ahora se mas cosas que desconocia como validar diferentes tipos de datos como listas, emails, telefonos.etc gracias amigo por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

El **operador !=** se hizo precisamente para saber si un valor es diferente del otro, no se si hay otra forma de saber si un valor es distinto de otro sin usar el **operador !=**, y de haberla sería tan engorrosa que no valiera la pena hacerlo.

A continuación te doy una solución y te explico donde está tu error lógico:

```
let valorInicial = parseInt(prompt(`Con un número especifica cuantos números quieres ordenar`));

if (valorInicial != '') 
{    
   if (valorInicial <= 0 || valorInicial == null || or valorInicial == algunaLetra) 
   {    
      alert('No ingresaste un número válido');    
   }
   else
   {
      ordernarN();
   }    
}
```

Tu error esta en la forma de hacer las condiciones:

Lo primero que debes hacer es preguntar si **valorInicial** está vacío y de no estarlo entonces caer en las otras validaciones, tu lo haces al revés, primero preguntas si no está vacío y de no estar vacío lo ordena, pero no estar vacío significa que **valorInicial** puede tener cualquier valor no válido.

Comment: Compa tienes toda la razon, estoy haciendo la validación al revés, lo cómico es que hace no mucho estoy aprendiendo Javascript y todas los IF los he venido haciendo asi, pero ahora en adelante tendre esto muy en cuenta, muchas gracias.

Comment: @AlexGarzón te agradeceria que le dieras un voto positivo a mi respuest si te fue util

Comment: No me deja por lo que es mi primera pregunta en el sitio, no tengo la suficiente reputacion.